# grails integration test giving java.lang.verify error for enum in domain

Tags: grails

I am using grails 2.2.0 when executing command test-app-integration -coverage it is giving  error

Error Exception occurred trigger event [TestPhasesEnd]: Could not create a new instance of class [AdminController]! (Use --stacktrace to see the full trace)
| Error Error executing script TestApp: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManagerPostProcessor': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: (class: com/cantina/lab/Movie$FileGroupVideo, method: whereAny signature: (Lgroovy/lang/Closure;)Lgrails/gorm/DetachedCriteria;) Incompatible type for getting or setting field

Answer (score 0):

Move the enum to src/groovy as a workaround. See [this jira issue.](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-9627), should be fixed in 2.2.1.

Comment: actually  domain class Movie  belongs to plugin gvps-0.3 i

Comment: com/cantina/lab/Movie$FileGroupVideo  this enum belongs to plugin class then how to resolve it

Comment: If you need it fixed as soon as possible you can fork the [gvps plugin](https://github.com/rvanderwerf/grails-video/) and move the enum. Otherwise you will have to wait until this bug is fixed or the plugin authors do this change on their own.